# Are there differences between the International and U.S. Editions of Dummit and Foote?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

I'm taking an abstract algebra course this fall and want the textbook over the summer. I found an international copy of Dummit and Foote Abstract Algebra 3rd ed. for much cheaper than the U.S. authorized version. Does anyone know if there is a difference in the texts? Definitely still an English printing. Or does anyone know of a way to check this other than a 400ish page comparison read.

Thanks. Please forgive any typos this was on an iPad.

Comment: I've bought several International Edition textbooks such as Rudin's PMA and Munkres' Topology. The main difference between them and the US editions (which are in the library) is the quality of paper and printing. The paper is a bit thinner and a bit more fragile. PMA has a few non-relevant typos as well. But, c'mon, you're paying about 90% less, so it is a fantastic deal.

Comment: Math Stack Exchange is not the place to ask about differences in editions of some book!